# onesignal does not register the playerid on onesignal sever after clicking on the subscribe button

Tags: onesignal

I'm using the following code and it generates a player-id but does not create id as a subscriber on the onesignal sever. How can I fix it?

I'm attaching the code and the error.

Error:

```
PUT https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/123232-33-44345-1234c-712312 400 ()
index.html:89 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: OneSignalUserSubscription is not defined
    at index.html:89
    at <anonymous>
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

<head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">


</head>


<body>

<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async></script>
<script>
    var useragentid = null;
    var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
    OneSignal.push(["init", {
        appId: "APP-ID",
        autoRegister: false,
        notifyButton: {
            enable: false
        },
        persistNotification: false
    }]);
    //Firstly this will check user id
    OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId) {
            if(userId == null){
                document.getElementById('unsubscribe').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else{
                useragentid = userId;
                document.getElementById('unsubscribe').style.display = '';
                OneSignal.push(["getNotificationPermission", function(permission){
                }]);
                OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled(function(isEnabled) {
                    if (isEnabled){
                        document.getElementById('unsubscribe').style.display = '';
                        document.getElementById('subscribe').style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById('unsubscribe').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('subscribe').style.display = '';
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    //Secondly this will check when subscription changed
    OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {
            if(isSubscribed==true){
                OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId) {
                    useragentid = userId;
                }).then(function(){

                    console.log(useragentid);
                    // this is custom function
                    // here you can send post request to php file as well.
                    OneSignalUserSubscription(useragentid);
                });
                document.getElementById('unsubscribe').style.display = '';
                document.getElementById('subscribe').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if(isSubscribed==false){
                OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId) {
                    useragentid = userId;
                });
                document.getElementById('unsubscribe').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('subscribe').style.display = '';
            }
            else{
                console.log('Unable to process the request');
            }
        });
    });
    function subscribeOneSignal(){
        if(useragentid !=null){
            OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
        }
        else{
            OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications({
                modalPrompt: true
            });
        }
    }
    function unSubscribeOneSignal(){
        OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
    }
</script>
<div id="home-top" class="clearfix">
    <p>OneSingle Testing</p>
    <br>
    <button id="subscribe" class="button" onclick="subscribeOneSignal()">Subscribe </button>
    <button id="unsubscribe" class="button" onclick="unSubscribeOneSignal()">Unsubscribe </button>
</div>
<style>
    .button {
        background-color: #008CBA;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the browser console to see what the response body is in the 400 error response. This should have an explanation for what's causing the 400 error.

Separately, you are calling a function named `OneSignalUserSubscription` but this function is not defined in your code, which is why you're getting the `ReferenceError`.

Comment: OneSignalUserSubscription is function which is a part of https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js